# Matplotlib video creation

Tags: matplotlib

**EDIT:  ImportanceOfBeingErnest provided the answer, however I am still inviting you all to explain, why is `savefig` logic different from `animation` logic.**

I want to make a video in `matplotlib`.  I went through manuals and examples and I just don't get it.  (regarding matplotlib, I always copy examples, because after five years of python and two years of mathplotlib I still understand 0.0% of matplotlib syntax)

After half a dozen hours here is what I came up to.  Well, I get empty video.  No idea why.

```
import os
import math
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

numb=100
temp=[0.0]*numb
cont=[0.0]*numb
for i in range(int(4*numb/10),int(6*numb/10)):
    temp[i]=2
    cont[i]=2

fig = plt.figure()
plts=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

plts.set_ylim([0,2.1])
plts.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plts.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ims = []

for i in range(1,10):
    line1, = plts.plot(range(0,numb),temp, linewidth=1, color='black')
    line2, = plts.plot(range(0,numb),cont, linewidth=1, color='red')
#    savefig is here for testing, works perfectly!
#    fig.savefig('test'+str(i)+'.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
    ims.append([line1,line2])
    plts.lines.remove(line1)
    plts.lines.remove(line2)
    for j in range(1,10):
        tempa=0
        for k in range (1,numb-1):
            tempb=temp[k]+0.51*(temp[k-1]-2*temp[k]+temp[k+1])
            temp[k-1]=tempa
            tempa=tempb
        temp[numb-1]=0
    for j in range(1,20):
        conta=0
        for k in range (1,numb-1):
            contb=cont[k]+0.255*(cont[k-1]-2*cont[k]+cont[k+1])
            cont[k-1]=conta
            conta=contb
        cont[numb-1]=0

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,blit=True)
im_ani.save('im.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why is my explanation not clear enough?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Your answer is clear in a sense of providing the solution, however I would really want to understand why is my logic wrong, i.e. what is going on behind these commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a plot which is not empty, the main idea would be not to remove the lines from the plot.

That is, delete the two lines

```
plts.lines.remove(line1)
plts.lines.remove(line2)
```

If you delete these two lines the output will look something like this

[image]
[[Link to orginial size animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czWao.gif)]

Now one might ask, why do I not need to remove the artist in each iteration step, as otherwise all of the lines would populate the canvas at once?

The answer is that the ArtistAnimation takes care of this. It will only show those  artists in the supplied list that correspond to the given time step. So while at the end of the for loop you end up with all the lines drawn to the canvas, once the animation starts they will all be removed and only one set of artists is shown at a time.

In such a case it is of course not a good idea to use the loop for saving the individual images as the final image would contain all of the drawn line at once,

[image]

The solution is then either to make two runs of the script, one for the animation, and one where the lines are removes in each timestep. Or, maybe better, use the animation istself to create the images.

```
im_ani.save('im.png', writer="imagemagick")
```

will create the images as `im-<nr>.png` in the current folder. It will require to have imagemagick installed.

---

I'm trying here to answer the two questions from the comments:

***1.*** I have appended line1 and line2 before deleting them. Still they disappeared in the final result. How come?

You have appended the lines to a list. After that you removed the lines from the axes. Now the lines are in the list but not part of the axes. When doing the animation, matplotlib finds the lines in the list and makes them visible.  But they are not in the axes (because they have been removed) so the visibility of some Line2D object, which does not live in any axes but only somewhere in memory, is changed. But that isn't reflected in the plot because the plot doesn't know this line any more.

***2.*** If I understand right, when you issue line1, = plts.plot... command then the line1 plot object is added to the plts graph object. However, if you change the line1 plot object by issuing line1, = plts.plot... command again, matplotlib does change line1 object but before that saves the old line1 to the plts graph object permanently. Is this what caused my problem?

No. The first step is correct, `line1, = plts.plot(..)` adds a Line2D object to the axes. However, in a later loop step `line1, = plts.plot()` creates **another** Line2D object and puts it to the canvas. The initial Line2D object is **not changed** and it doesn't know that there is now some other line next to it in the plot. Therefore, if you don't remove the lines they will all be visible in the static plot at the end.

Comment: The point is that data in the plot should change, different data for each picture in the video.  So the main problem is that the whole logic of the problem is probably completely wrong, but I cannot help myself because I don't understand anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the point about the whole logic beeing wrong. I find it quite logical not to remove something that should be shown.

Comment: Interestingly, if I delete those two lines, produced PNGs will be wrong.  How come?  One logic for savefig and the other for videos??

Comment: I had to remove it, because otherwise all plots accumulate on the last PNG

Comment: OK, since you answered to my question, I will accept it.  Hopefully someone provides the explanation why is it different for `savefig`and `animation` later on.

Comment: What I don't understand are two things: 1. I have appended line1 and line2 **before** deleting them.  Still they disappeared in the final result.  How come?  2. If I understand right, when you issue `line1, = plts.plot...` command then the `line1` plot object is added to the `plts` graph object.  However, if you change the `line1` plot object by issuing `line1, = plts.plot...` command again, matplotlib does change `line1` object but **before that saves** the old `line1` to the `plts` graph object permanently.  Is this what caused my problem?

Comment: I addressed your two questions in an edit to my answer.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that `line1` and `line2` are simply pointers?  So when you append them, pointers are copied, but after deleting lines copied pointers to empty lines?

Comment: You do not delete the lines and there are no empty lines. Apart from that, sure, most python objects are pointers.