# matplotlib ArtistAnimation returns a blank video

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, networkx

I'm trying to produce an animation of a networkx graph changing over time. I'm using the networkx_draw utilities to create matplotlib figures of the graph, and matplotlib's ArtistAnimation module to create an animation from the artists networkx produces. I've made a minimum reproduction of what I'm doing here:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Instantiate the graph model
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)

# Keep track of highest node ID
G.maxNode = 2

fig = plt.figure()
nx.draw(G)
ims = []

for timeStep in xrange(10):

    G.add_edge(G.maxNode,G.maxNode+1)
    G.maxNode += 1

    pos = nx.drawing.spring_layout(G)
    nodes = nx.drawing.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
    lines = nx.drawing.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)

    ims.append((nodes,lines,))
    plt.pause(.2)
    plt.cla()

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200,            repeat_delay=3000,blit=True)
im_ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})
```

The process works fine while displaying the figures live, it produces exactly the animation I want. And it even produces a looping animation in a figure at the end of the script, again what I want, which would suggest that the animation process worked. However when I open the "im.mp4" file saved to disk, it is a blank white image which runs for the expected period of time, never showing any of the graph images which were showed live.

I'm using networkx version 1.11, and matplotlib version 2.0. I'm using ffmpeg for the animation, and am running on a Mac, OSX 10.12.3.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: If you don't want to have an empty animation, do not clear the axes! I.e. remove the line `plt.cla()`. You should then also remove the initial `nx.draw(G)`, because this is not added to the `ims` array and would otherwise stick around in every frame of the animation.

The reasons and a longer explanation can be found in this question,
[Matplotlib video creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914491/matplotlib-video-creation), where a similar case is tackled.

The drawback is of course that when removing the `plt.cla()` you'll end up with a crowded animation on screen; so you need to decide whether to plot on screen or whether to save beforehands.