# Matplotlib animation blank for the first few frames in saved .mp4 file

Tags: python, matplotlib, mp4

I'm trying to run a pretty slow animation (500 milliseconds per frame) using matplotlib's FuncAnimation framework. When I do this and save the result as a .mp4 file the first few seconds are always blank when I use the Windows 10 "Movies & TV" app, or frozen when I use the "Windows Media Player" app. I don't like this. Is it a bug, a misuse on my part, or an unavoidable artifact of the framework?

Here's a minimal example pulled straight from [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/animation_api.html) -- I just added the `interval=500` keyword argument to `FuncAnimation`, and then saved the animation in the standard way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, interval=500, blit=True)
plt.show()

ani.save("Example.mp4", dpi=200)
```

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914491/matplotlib-video-creation) to be very helpful

Comment: @r-beginners I do not understand how that answer relates to my problem of having **a few** blank frames at the beginning followed by a working animation. Additionally, that answer seems to be using a different technique to generate the animations (using `ArtistAnimation` rather than `FuncAnimation`).